# Closure Challenge: returning same output from first call (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, closures

I am facing the following challenge description:

"Write a function once that accepts a callback as input and returns a function. When the returned function is called the first time, it should call the callback and return that output. If it is called any additional times, instead of calling the callback again it will simply return the output value from the first time it was called"

The code given to you is:

```
function addByX(x) {
  return function(num) {
    return num + x;
  };
}

var addByTwo = addByX(2);

function once(func) {
  // ADD CODE HERE
}

var onceFunc = once(addByTwo);

// UNCOMMENT THESE TO TEST YOUR WORK!
console.log(onceFunc(4));  //should log 6
console.log(onceFunc(10));  //should log 6
console.log(onceFunc(9001));  //should log 6
```

I can get the code to return what you would expect it to(6, 12, 9003), but I cannot get it to continue logging 6. onceFunc itself equals addByTwo with x being equal to 2, so then any number passed into onceFunc acts as the n. Do I need to get it to save the first return of 6 or the n=4 into a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better solution, but this is what I came up with. I tried adding comments to the code to explain what it's doing, but if you have any addition questions, let me know: https://jsfiddle.net/nvd9dqza/6/

```
function addByX(x) {
  return function(num) {
    return num + x;
  };
}

var addByTwo = addByX(2);

function once(func) {
    // a variable which is scoped to the "once" function
  // this means you can't access "result" outside of the function
    var result;
  return function(num){
    // since this function is scoped inside "once", it has access to result
    // set the result to itself (if aleady called), or the value returned from func
    result = result || func(num);

    // return the result
    return result;
  }
}

var onceFunc = once(addByTwo);

// UNCOMMENT THESE TO TEST YOUR WORK!
console.log(onceFunc(4));  //should log 6
console.log(onceFunc(10));  //should log 6
console.log(onceFunc(9001));  //should log 6
```

Comment: The closure part is good, but see if you can add logic to prevent the call back being called more than once if it returns 0 the first time. Not sure if you are being marked on this, but good luck.

Comment: Good point. You could handle this two ways... `result = result === undefined ? func(num) : result` but that has the pitfall if func returns undefined. Alternatively, you could add another scoped variable `called` set to false initially and set to true after calling `func`. Then hook to that to know what to return. It depends on how much you trust the calling function.